# Confused about navigation in modal / non modal windows in prism - Need guidance

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-5

I am all confused going about implementing this in Prism.  My scenario in one liner is how to achieve Prism Navigation (regionManager.RequestNavigate) in a view that is shown as a separate modal/non modal window over the main window.

Taking some code from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36745/Showing-Dialogs-When-Using-the-MVVM-Pattern), I am now able to show a separate Window, but I am very confused about navigating in the regions of the window shown. I will try to put up some code below to clarify my situation.

This code in **RoomBandViewModel** launches dialog

```
private void ManageRoomFacility() {
    dialogService.ShowDialog<RoomFacilityMainWindowView>(this, container.Resolve<RoomFacilityMainWindowView>());
    regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.Main_Region, new Uri("RoomFacilityMainView", UriKind.Relative));
```

As can be seen, I launch the Dialog which shows the View (code shown below), and then tries to navigate in One of the region of the View

The popup window **RoomFacilityMainWindowView**

```
<Window x:Class="HotelReservation.Main.View.RoomFacilities.RoomFacilityMainWindowView"

    <view:RoomFacilityMainView 
        prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static const:RegionNames.Window_Main_Region}"/>

</Window>
```

UserControl within window (**RoomFacilityMainView**)

```
<UserControl x:Class="HotelReservation.Main.View.RoomFacilities.RoomFacilityMainView"
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        ...
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource RegionBorderStyle}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Sample Text"/>
                <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static const:RegionNames.Window_List_Region}"
                            />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <GridSplitter Width="5" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <Border Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource RegionBorderStyle}" >
            <TabControl x:Name="Items" Margin="5" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static const:RegionNames.Window_Edit_Region}"  />
        </Border>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind (**RoomFacilityMainView.xaml.cs**)

```
public partial class RoomFacilityMainView : UserControl {

    public RoomFacilityMainView() {
        InitializeComponent();

        RoomFacilityMainViewModel viewModel = this.DataContext as RoomFacilityMainViewModel;
        if (viewModel == null) {
            viewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<RoomFacilityMainViewModel>();
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

**RoomFacilityMainViewModel**
    public class RoomFacilityMainViewModel : BindableBase {

```
    IRegionManager regionManager;
    IUnityContainer container;

    public RoomFacilityMainViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer container) {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
        this.container = container;

        regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.Window_List_Region, new Uri("RoomFacilityListView", UriKind.Relative));

    }
}
```

With this code no navigation occurs and I just get a blank window. The Contents of the RoomFacilityListView.xaml should be displayed, but its blank.

If the code is confusing, then please just give advice on how to navigate (use RequestNavigate) with View that has regions but shown through Dialog Service as a separate window instead of on MainWindow(Shell) .

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an `IDialogService` implementation that shows a new window via `Window.ShowDialog()` method, then there's is no surprise that your navigation doesn't work. The `ShowDialog()` method returns only on closing the window, so your navigation request will actually be processed on a closed window, in particular **after** the window has closed.

There is nothing special in modal windows that would prevent using Prism regions and navigation in them. One limitation is that you cannot create multiple window instances "as is", since they all would have regions with same names, and that's not possible using one region manager. However, there is a solution: scoped region managers.

Assuming you're not going to create multiple instances, here is an example how could you solve your issue.

First, you have to ensure that your modal dialog's `RegionManager` is the same instance as your main `RegionManager` (I'm using MEF here, but actually it doesn't matter):

```
[Export]
public partial class Dialog : Window
{
    private readonly IRegionManager rm;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Dialog(IRegionManager rm)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.rm = rm;

        // Don't forget to set the attached property to the instance value
        RegionManager.SetRegionManager(this, this.rm);
    }
}
```

Now, extend your dialog service implementation with a method that accepts a navigation callback:

```
bool? ShowDialog<T>(object ownerViewModel, object viewModel, Action initialNavigationCallback = null) where T : Window
{

    Window dialog = /* your instance creation code, e.g. using container */;
    dialog.Owner = FindOwnerWindow(ownerViewModel);
    dialog.DataContext = viewModel;

    if (initialNavigationCallback != null)      
    {
        dialog.Loaded += (s, e) => initialNavigationCallback();
    }

    return dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

This will provide you a possibility to display a dialog with an initial navigation request, you can call it e.g. like this:

```
void ManageRoomFacility() {
    dialogService.ShowDialog<RoomFacilityMainWindowView>(
        this, 
        container.Resolve<RoomFacilityMainWindowView>(),
        () => regionManager.RequestNavigate(
            RegionNames.Main_Region, 
            new Uri("RoomFacilityMainView", UriKind.Relative))
        );
```

Alternatively, you can use the [state based navigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec2) for your task. There is a sample implementation of a **Send Message** modal dialog in the [State-Based Navigation QuickStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405495(v=pandp.40).aspx).

```
<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding SendMessageRequest}">
    <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True"> 
        <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            <vs:SendMessagePopupView />
        </prism: PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
    </prism:PopupWindowAction>
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```